# HTML Form onsubmit go to html fragment

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html form which I have overwritten the onsubmit method to send an AJAX POST request.

On success I then want to display a "thank you" message and move the users browser to that thank you message.

I was going to move the page via a html fragment but unsure how to kick this off via javascript?

Comment: Would you mind giving us a few file names and some sample code.  This will allow much more targeted and useful help.

Comment: If you're re-directing anyway, why bother sending the data via ajax?

Comment: Are you using a library such as jQuery or is this just vanilla JavaScript?

Comment: JQuery.

I want to redirect to a html fragment on the same page, but submit data to another URL.

Comment: Think I've got it with 

$('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#cform").offset().top
        }, 1000);

Answer (score 0):

A working example. The "callback" function would be your ajax callback:

```js
$('#source').click(function callback(){
    $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: $('#target').offset().top
    }, 1000);
});
```

```css
#source,
#target {
    margin-bottom: 1000px; /* simulate space between elements */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="source">Source click me</button>
<div id="target">Target</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could easily just change the `innerHTML` of the element the form is in.  Something like this as your success callback:

```
function() {
  $('#form').html('<p>You submitted the form. Yay!</p>');
}
```